# Decorator for class which decorates all methods

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to write class decorator which for all non-magic methods, to decorate these methods. The idea is that to all methods of class print its name after call; I do not want decor all methods but only class. Decorator `log_method` works. I have problem with `log_class` decorator. There are no errors and no output.

```
import traceback
import inspect

def log_method(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("{}{}".format(int(len(traceback.extract_stack()) / 2) * " ", func.__name__))

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner

def log_class(cls):
    for m in dir(cls):
        if not m.startswith("__") and inspect.isfunction(getattr(cls, m)):
            m = log_method(m)
            print(m)
    return cls

@log_class
class Cls:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def A(self):
        self.B()

    def B(self):
        self.C()

    def C(self):
        pass


Cls().A()
"""
Excepted output:
A
 B
  C
"""
```

Comment: `m = log_method(m)` just assigns to the variable `m` the return value of `log_method`, it doesn't affect the class at all.

Answer (score 3):

You should rebind the method to the class object using [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) passing the method name `m`; assigning to the local name `m` like you've done, does nothing.

More so, you're currently passing `m`, a string, to `log_method`. Instead, you should pass the function object itself after retrieving via `getattr`:

```
def log_method(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("{}{}".format(int(len(traceback.extract_stack()) / 2) * " ", func.__name__))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

def log_class(cls):
    for m in dir(cls):
        if not m.startswith("__") and inspect.isfunction(getattr(cls, m)):
            setattr(cls, m, log_method(getattr(cls, m))) # here
    return cls
```

---

```
Cls.A()
#  A
#   B
#    C
```

PS: `log_method` is never used for decorating, so it's not a decorator.

Comment: @PM2Ring Throw in a metaclass, and the answer becomes a vortex, more likely so, if OP has no previous experience with those :)